# Однородны ли определения, нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?
Упавшая (?) сломанная игрушка.

Comment: Тут важен контекст, потому что неоднородные может быть уместно (а то и желательно) использовать как однородные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неоднородные.

*Сломанная* — указывает на состояние.
*Упавшая* — на её местоположение (допустим, не на полке, а на полу).

Однородность проверяется вставкой И: *упавшая и сломанная игрушка*. || Плохо подходит.

Пояснение (другая возможная причина запятой) там тоже не подходит, потому что упавшая игрушка может быть и целой (несломанной).